# Android Volley not work json object

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I have this website that has this
 `{"pro":[{"Precio":"36,00 ","Code":"Suscrip12"}]}` 
json object,
when I try to retrieve data through Volley, with this code,

```
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "https://www.example.com/end-point", "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

            try {

              JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("pro");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject productsjson = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String precio = productsjson.getString("Precio");
                    String sku = productsjson.getString("code");



                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());


    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);

}
```

I get the following result:

```
{"pro":[]}
```

I have other web service with the same structure and all work well. I also tried the address of the web service with Postman and returns the correct object,could you please help me to solve this?

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you try to access the URL from a browser what do you get? Does it return the JSON string as you expect?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla asked to test in mobile browser. If its getting back expected data or not

Comment: Returns the json correctly through the URL object.

Comment: Just I check it on a tablet and returns me {"pro": []}, ie a mobile browser is not doing well. In the pc itself.

Comment: Also change productsjson.getString("code"); to productsjson.getString("Code");

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved, the commentary on the mobile browser has given me the clue it was. It was I had to send user authentication header in the request as json. Noting that did not work in the mobile browser, I logged on the web and immediately worked perfectly. Adding headers works well. Although just I not understand why. The web service does not require authentication. Thanks Stallion